# Text File Index?

Tags: ios, text-files

Good afternoon,

I am wanting to create a a Text file with a many different paragraphs. I want to show a different one everyday. Is there a way to create s sort of index and display a new paragraph each day?

I crated the app already, and the way I am updating is by going into my server and editing the text file and then downloading it into the app, and I have to update it every day and I don't want to do that anymore. I have about 2 years worth of daily paragraphs that I can simply have them all in a text file. I'm not sure if an index is the right approach to this.

I want to be able to have like a huge list of text paragraphs and then displaying a different one each day. Is there any way to do this? I am open to different suggestions! I just want to get it to work! Maybe someone can guide me through the right path.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, start with **the simplest thing that could possibly work**:

- Make a text file with all your paragraphs. Download the entire file into your app. In your app, split the file into paragraphs, choose one at random, and display it.

Now, if the above proves too slow, then consider optimising it. You could:

- After downloading the text file (the first time), read through the file once and create an index with the offset of the start of each paragraph. Then, choose an index entry at random, seek to that point in the text file, read the paragraph, and display it.

Or, you could:

- Create the index on the server and download it along with the text file. That saves the app from having to create the index itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now, I don't have to download the text file. I can simply create text file and add it to the app so that it can be used offline as well. Now, how can I just call a next paragraph from the list? Is there like a format I need to have in the text file? Thanks!

Comment: I would either: (a) Store each paragraph as one (long) line of text, or (b) Format it with a blank line between each paragraph. I would probably choose (a) because you're going to have to format it for your device screen anyway.

Comment: very well. I will look into that! I found this question: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102512/how-to-read-a-random-line-from-a-textfile)_italic_ Is there a way to read the next line and next line every time I call it the function?

Comment: @MichaelOrtiz See my answer for help pulling out a single paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably easier/better ways to do this, but here's what I'd do...

I'd reorganize your text file into a CSV with two columns.  The column on the left has the date paragraph should be displayed (in an easy to parse format), and the column on the right has the actual paragraph.  When the app is first launched, it goes to the web, downloads and parses this whole file.

In your app, store these paragraphs in an `NSDictionary`, using the date as the key, and the paragraph as the value.

Now encode this `NSDictionary` to disc.

From now on, you don't need to redownload/reparse the file.  You can just check in that dictionary, find the entry with the right date, and display that.

---

Now, ideally, you'd want your server to be able to tell your app when the file was last updated, and for your app to keep track of when it last downloaded the file.  Any time the server's last update date is more recent than the app's last download date, the app should redownload, reparse, resave the file.

---

If you don't want to store the dates, you can simple put the paragraphs in a line separated `.txt` file.  When you read the file in, you can store each paragraph into a separate array index very simply by doing something like this:

```
NSArray *paragraphs = [myTextDocContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
    [NSCharacterSet newLineCharacterSet]];
```